# Looping through large data sets

Tags: powershell, dataset

I have 2 large data sets (>25K records each) and I'm trying to find records based on a common key.  The short of it is I need to pull fields out of the second data set based on that common key.  Unfortunately, the common key can be in one of two columns.

I setup a nested *foreach* scenario, however it's taking exceptionally long to process through the records.  The end goal is to build a custom PSObject with data fields from each dataset.

```
foreach($MPD in $MPDS.Tables.Rows){
    $i++
    Write-Host "Outter: $i"
    $linkedID = "http://site/" + $MPD.ID

    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MPDLinkedID -Value $linkedID
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name OrderID -Value $MPD.OrderID
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DSID -Value $MPD.MDS_ID
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CreatedBy -Value $MPD.CreatedBy    
    foreach($DS in $DSTwoRecords.Tables.rows){
        $j++
        Write-Host "Inner: $j"
        if(($MPD.MDS_ID -eq $DS.ID) -or ($MPD.ExternalRefernceID -eq $DS.DSID)){
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DSID -Value $DS.Code
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DeliveryDate -Value $DS.DeliveryDate
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DeliveryLocation -Value $DS.DeliveryLocation
        }
    }
    $AllRecords += $obj

}
return $AllRecords
```

With the size of the datasets this loop has been running greater than 10 hours so far.

Is there a more efficient/better way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Tried to embed the image, link below:

[Sample Data Sets and desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Sz8A.jpg)

Comment: You could try if using a DataRelation as [mentioned here](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/dataview-with-datas-from-several-tables/) can speed up things; the example still uses nested foreach tho.

Comment: can you offer sample data of the source?

Comment: Thanks Filburt, will do some research on DataRelation.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no sequential dependencies between the data sets, you could use **Start-job** cmdlet instead of the inner loop to have some concurrency.